# how to pass data from controller in multiple view

Tags: codeigniter

what i want is to pass data from controller in multiple view in codeigniter, for example

```
function main(){
    $data['test'] = 'test';
    $json['json'] = $data
    $this->load->view('template/ajax', $json);
}
```

but i also want to load that data in $this->load->view('home', $json) aside from "template/ajax", i/ve tried this code but it did not work.

```
function main(){ 
    $data['test'] = 'test';
    $data['otherview'] = $this->load->view('home', $data);
    $json['json'] = $data
    $this->load->view('template/ajax', $json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem but this is how I do it with arrays:

```
public $test = array();

function  __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->variable['testing'] = "Testing Content";
}

function main() {
   $this->load->view('home', var_dump($this->variable));
}

function secondView {
    $this->load->view('template/ajax', var_dump($this->variable));
}
```

Then just echo a defined $variable on your view file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$data['otherview'] = $this->load->view('home', $data, true);
```

See CI manual: [returning views as data](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)